# Orphan replicasets when running "kubectl apply" with a new image tag

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

My deployment `yml` file tags my image with the build version.

So everytime I run `kubectl apply` from my release pipeline, it pulls the image and deploys it properly.

My question is about the `replicaset`: when I run `kubectl get all`, I see orphan replicasets from the pods that were terminated from the previous images. (At least, that's my understanding.) The `desired`, `current` and `ready` properties of these orphan replicasets are 0.

Will this lead to some sort of memory leak? Should I run any other command before `kubectl apply`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you upgrade your deployments from version 1 to version 2, the Deployment creates a new ReplicaSet and increases the count of replicas while the previous count goes to 0. Details [here](https://v1-17.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#updating-a-deployment_)

If you try to execute another rolling update from version 2 to version 3, you might notice that at the end of the upgrade, you have two ReplicaSets with a count of 0.

**How this benefit us?**

Imagine that current version of the pod introduces any problem and you might want to rollback to previous version. If you have old ReplicaSet, you could scale current to 0 and increment the old ReplicaSet count. See how  [Rolling Back to a Previous Revision](https://v1-17.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#rolling-back-to-a-previous-revision).

By default Kubernetes stores the last 10 ReplicaSets and lets you rollback to any of them. But you can change this by changing the `spec.revisionHistoryLimit` in your Deployment. Ref: [Clean up Policy](https://v1-17.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#clean-up-policy)

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 3
...
```